# How to send response only with set fields using dropwizard

Tags: json, jackson, dropwizard

I'm using dropwizard and when I'm sending response, Jackson translates my response class into response JSON.

The problem is that there is one field of POJO class that is not always set and when it isn't set it show null value in response JSON.

```
someField:null
```

But I want to show this field only in case if it is set. 
What should I do? Maybe there is some annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as I found jackson has annotation that allows you to exclude field. Actually it doesn't exclude field, but includes it in some case that you could choose.
The answer is:  @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL). It includes this field only in case if it not null.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way to do this. In your POJO at the class level add

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) //or Include.NON_EMPTY
public static class Request {
  // ...
}
```

You could also do this globally by using

```
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

Here's the reference: http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html